# Gradle - Camel Case for task names - First character UPPER case

Tags: gradle, export, task, global, uppercase

I have seen few Gradle / Groovy docs and they mention, you can create a task name like this:

```
task kobaLory { 
  // some code here... 
}

task noPrint << {
  // some code here
}

task titu (...) {
    ...
}

task doThisSpecialThing {
 ...
}
```

etc

Does Gradle provides a way to define task as exported / global task if I make the first character of the task name as UPPER case, see below. I know there's $GRADLE_HOME/init.d where if you have someglobalfile.gradle and define the tasks there, you'll have those for free in any Gradle process but I'm just asking if we just change the first character of the task name to UPPER case.

```
task KobaLory { 
  // some code here... 
}

task NoPrint << {
  // some code here
}

task Titu (...) {
    ...
}

task DoThisSpecialThing {
 ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

By convention, Gradle task names start with a lowercase letter. Technically, capitalization is irrelevant.